# Alinear float en div

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de alinear varios div dentro de uno con float. Aca dejo un ejemplo. Mi idea es colocar varios boxs no solo 3.

```css
.cont {margin: 0 auto; width: 720px;}
.thumm {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

.thumm-box {
border: 1px solid #888;
display:inline-block;
width: 220px;
padding: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<p style="border: 1px solid #888;">linea</p>
<div class="thumm">

<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 1
</div>

<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 2
</div>

<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 3
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: y cuál es tu problema? los divs se están alineando bien

Comment: Me falto agregar un parrafo. Con ese parrafo, se ve que no esta alineado.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es tener todos los divs uno al lado del otro, sólo tienes que sacar la propiedad margin-right: 40px; de la clase thum-box.

Comment: Si, pero como le doy espacio entre box y box?

Comment: Puedes setear un margin más chico, de unos pocos px

Comment: Ahi hice otro cambio en cual, investigando un poco llegue a usar **display: inline-block;**, el problema ahora es tratar de quitar **padding** y hacer espacio entre cada box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes setear el margin-right con un valor de 2px:

```css
.cont {margin: 0 auto; width: 720px;}
.thumm {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

.thumm-box {
border: 1px solid #888;
display:inline-block;
width: 220px;
padding: 17px;
margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<p style="border: 1px solid #888;">linea</p>
<div class="thumm">

<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 1
</div>

<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 2
</div>

<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 3
</div>
<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 4
</div>
<div class="thumm-box">
thumm box 5
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jajajajaja.... no se me ocurrio agregar el **margin**.... gracias!